# Create a Time Lapse Video with Adobe Premiere

Tags: video, premiere, time-lapse, cs5

I have a video clip that is one hour long and I would like to compress it down to 60 seconds. Anyone know the easiest way to do this with Premiere?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to play back your footage at 60x the original speed such that one hour fits in one minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of Premiere, there should actually be a speed adjustment from the context menu when you right click on the clip.  It may be under a sub-menu depending on version, but it will give you the option of either a % to increase/decrease the speed by or a new time that you want the clip to take.